# Inserir mesmo dado em duas colunas MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Olá!
Possuo uma tabela com o nome tabx e duas colunas y e z, quando vou inserir os valores na coluna y preciso que um trigger copie esse valor para a coluna z.
Já tentei algumas soluções mas sem sucesso alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Tem como você colocar o que você tentou aqui?

Comment: Está precisando disso para um insert manual ou está desenvolvendo um software? O simples fato de colocar o nome da variável no lugar da coluna não resolve? digamos que o nome da variável que vai colocar na coluna `y` seja `k` então o insert ficaria assim: `insert into tabx (y, z) values (k, k)` só pra saber mesmo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+ou- isto

CREATE TRIGGER ins_tabela BEFORE INSERT ON tabela
  FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
     SET NEW.z = new.y; 
 END;//

Comment: Tente elaborar uma resposta mais explicativa. :]

Comment: Perfeito Motta resolveu meu problema. Muito Obrigado!!!